# FactoryGirl - overwrite deep related object attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I have some not too common issue with factory. I've got several models related with each other. I created quite fine factory that creates that whole "chain" invoking only below

```
FactoryGirl.create(:application)
```

Above command creates like I've mentioned before several related models. I user Faker to populate attributes' names. Everything works fine but, I would like to overwrite one deep related model called 'service' with application model. I thought about trait but I can't invoke that trait within

```
trait :my_trait do
  name 'Overwritten name'
end

FactoryGirl.create(:application, :my_trait)
```

Obviously above is wrong because trait regards to application instead of nested service model. One solution I found is update it after create factory but I would prefer to do it more globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these cases we usually create a separate "lower" instance and pass that to the "upper" instance.

Like:

```
service = FactoryGirl.build(:service, name: 'Something else')
application = FactoryGirl.create(:application, service: service)
```

Of course you could also achieve the same behavior if you use this pattern very much in your codebase with the following factory:

```
factory :application do
  transient do
    service_name nil
  end

  association :service

  after(:build) do |application, evaluator|
    if evaluator.service_name
      application.service.name = evaluator.service_name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: application does not have a service, it is related through severals model like I 've mentioned. Here is just my problem.

Comment: Then you would need to create the "middle" instance(s) as well or use the second example.

Comment: callback and ignore statment it was what I was looking for! Thanks a lot :)